# Reversibility of independent exchange rates

Tags: algorithms

A project has two tasks:

```
Task A takes 1 hour, Task B task 4 hours.
```

For this project we enter dollars as the cost currency.

```
It costs $100/hr, so task A costs $100, and task B costs $400.
Overall the project costs $500
```

However this project is one of many, each having different currencies, so we would like to convert the costs to the base currency used by all projects, which is euros.

Now the conversion rate is contractually specified per activity, in this case

```
task A has a conversion rate of 1 euro = 4 dollars
task B has a conversion rate of 1 euro = 2 dollars.
```

Thus converting task A to euros is

```
$100 / 4 = 25 euros
```

converting task B to euros is

```
$400 / 2 = 200 euros
```

Thus the entire project is 225 euros.

All seems fine.

However what if things worked the other way. we entered in euros, but want to convert to dollars?

Well task A is 1/5 of the total,

```
so task A is 225 euros * 1/5 = 45 euros
task B is 225 euros * 4/5 = 180 euros
```

now converting to dollars

```
task A is 45 euros * 4 = $180
task B is 180 euros * 2 = $360
```

Thus the total cost of the project in dollars is $540

This isn't good. I want this calculation to be reversible but 500isnot540, and that is obviously not just 'rounding error'. There is a flaw in my algorithm.

What do i need to do to make these conversions reversible?

Comment: The cost of task $A$ is $1/5$ in dollars but $1/8$ in Euros. The cost in dollars is the same as the time cost because the rate (dollar per hour) is the same for the two tasks. It's not the same in Euro.